# Webex Bot integration in .netcore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, botframework, chatbot, webex

I am new to the Bot framework, I am trying to integrate WebEx Bot with my .NET core application. can anyone give sample code for integrating the WebEx Bot. Suggest any forum to check

I created sample Bot which is on the Bot framework template and I have modified some changes and works as expected. Now i want to integrate webex bot. Could anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

There is a BotBuilder-Community dotnet sample, called [Webex Adapter Sample](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/samples/Webex%20Adapter%20Sample), you can reference that demonstrates integrating the two together. The sample is based off of the BotBuilder-Community dotnet library located [here](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Webex).